# How to access the file in The rails project by gem?

Tags: ruby, file, ruby-on-rails-4

```
File.open(File.join(__dir__, 'config/global_nav_data.yml'))
```

The rails project where my gem got installed will have some file inside config folder. I have to get that file in the project. I tried the above but it is fetching file in the gem not in the project .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'global_nav_data.yml'))
```

One probably wants to add a check for `Rails` is defined, like:

```
if Kernel.const_defined? 'Rails'
  File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'global_nav_data.yml'))
else
  raise 'I need Rails to run!'
end
```